# Detecting a change in one of two UITextFields

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios6

I am trying detect if there have been any changes in one of two `UITextfields`. The two text fields have tags (1 and 2) and the initial value is stored in a variable. On edit it compares the new value with the variable and if there is a change makes the `setHeadingsButton` visible.

I have the first text field linked to the delegate in ViewDidLoad:

```
impactLabel1.delegate = self;
```

and so the following works for text field impactLabel1 but it will not obviously work for the impactLabel2.

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *) textField
{
if (textField.tag == 1)
{
  if (impactLabel1.text != impactlabel1)
  {
  [setHeadingsButton setAlpha:1];
  }
}
if (textField.tag==2)
{
  if (impactLabel2.text != impactlabel2)
  {
  [setHeadingsButton setAlpha:1];
  }
}
```

How do you correctly link both text fields to the delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *) textField
{
if (textField.tag == 1)
{
  if (![impactLabel1.text isEqualToString:impactlabel1])
  {
  [setHeadingsButton setAlpha:1];
  }
}
if (textField.tag==2)
{
  if (![impactLabel2.text isEqualToString:impactlabel2])
  {
  [setHeadingsButton setAlpha:1];
  }
}
```

EDIT:

In .h file assign delegates

```
<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

for delegate method make sure that you have bind delegate from xib like..

[image]

OR

in viewDidLoad write following code

```
self.myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Thanks but the comparing is not the issue. It is that textFieldDidEndEditing is not called when the second text box is edited because the delegate is only linked to the first. I am trying to work out how you link the delegate to both text fields.

Comment: have you added the textFields from xib, or with coding

Comment: Thanks. I added the text fields in the storyboard. Can I do what you are saying for both text fields?

Comment: I have tried that: impactLabel1.delegate = self; but as soon as I then add the next one impactLabel2.delegate = self; it stops the firt from working.

Comment: Thanks - I got there in the end. I needed to set the delegate to each text field in the storyboard, not using impactLabel*.delegate = self; Thank you for your help.